# Deploying a ruby on a rails app with cPanel without SSH connection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cpanel

Unfortunately I'm not allowed to use special rails hosting on this project and my host does not allowed ssh on shared hosting.

So, I'm left with deploying my app with cPanel, but I'm puzzled.

My app is ready, finished and tested locally.

I created the rails app on cPanel, done the rewrite and I don't know the next step.
How do I upload my code (maybe with filezilla but where) and how do you install gems?

I've been looking all over the internet for this information.

Thanks

Comment: You might be able to deal with gems by censoring everything into the app, but I would have thought you'll still need ssh access for migrations and so on

Comment: Good question. I am a rails guy, but also have some LAMP apps that run on CPanel. I have looked at trying to deploy on CPanel, but have not found very good documentation.